# Pass arguments with white spaces to batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, arguments

I am so sure answer is as simple as passing "" to the arguments in batch file. But this fails. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
Test.bat env "Some cmd"
```

This "Some cmd" is another command that needs to run in environment set by env.

Test.bat:

```
Something like  set Env with %1%

set cmd=%2%

%cmd%
```

The above fails with '"Some cmd"' is not recognized as a cmd.

Only way I can get this to work is if I use "%cmd%" in batch file. Is this right?

Comment: after asking 10 questions, you should have learned to format your questions properly by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to specify path where   "Some cmd" is present.

Comment: Once my envioronment loads, "Some cmd" is recognized automatically.(Environment takes care of setting the %apth%).

Comment: Instead of using %2%, try only %2. i.e. remove trailing %

Comment: I passed args as Test.bat env "Some cmd"

Comment: set cmd=%2 and calle command with %cmd% and I still get the same ;"Some cmd"' is not recognized as a cmd message.

Comment: Do you can start "Some cmd" with the quotes from the command line?

Comment: I am now using %* to get the rest of the commmands, so I can pass without the " " and this works. Thanks all.